# How do I edit the csv file name in ReactJS when getting downloaded from the Table component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv

I have a button in ReactJS existing application where if the button is clicked the contents in the table gets incorporated in a csv file. I wanted to edit the name of the csv file.
This is the built in file where the download function is used.

This is CommonDataTable file where the Table and its options such as "download csv" , "filters" are coming from.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import './DataTable.css';

var rowData = [];
const getMuiTheme = () =>
    createMuiTheme({
      overrides: {
        MUIDataTable: {
          root: {
            backgroundColor: '#AAF',
            fontSize : '.875rem',
            fontFamily: 'Roboto,Arial,sans-serif',
            paper: {
            boxShadow: 'none',
          },
        },       
      },
    }
    });

const CommonDataTabel = (props) => {
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(true);
    const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);

    const options = {
        selectableRows: 'none',
        rowsPerPage: 10,
        rowsPerPageOptions: [5, 10, 25],
        fixedHeader:true
    }

    return (
        <div>
         <MuiThemeProvider theme={getMuiTheme()}>
            <MUIDataTable
                title={props.title}
                data={props.data}
                columns={props.columns}
                options={props.options}
            />
           </MuiThemeProvider>
        </div>

    );

}

export default CommonDataTabel
```

`download: ToolbarButton; /** * An object of options to change the output of the csv file. * @default`{ filename: 'abcdefg.csv', separator: ',' } `*/ downloadOptions: Partial<{ filename: string; separator: string; filterOptions: Partial<{ useDisplayedColumnsOnly: boolean; useDisplayedRowsOnly: boolean }>; }>;`

I tried of finding the exact place where I could edit the file name with dynamic functionality. It changes as per conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Just update the options object with `downloadOptions`

```
const options = {
  selectableRows: "none",
  rowsPerPage: 10,
  rowsPerPageOptions: [5, 10, 25],
  fixedHeader: true,
  downloadOptions: { filename: "your_file_name.csv", separator: "," }
};
```

You can learn about more options here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mui-datatables#options